# How can I set the cache lifetime?

Tags: python, django, django-sessions

I am trying to implement the function remember me, when the user has not ticked remember me, then the cache should be cleared after closing the browser, the saved data in the cache was deleted. For some reason my implementation doesn't work. When debugging, I get the value from POST correctly and there are no errors when setting the cookie lifetime. Tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
class AccountLoginView(LoginView):
    template_name = 'login.html'
    form_class = AccountLoginForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        remember = self.request.POST.get('remember-me', False)
        if not remember:
            self.request.session.set_expiry(0)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: See also [Django Note](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#browser-length-sessions-vs-persistent-sessions): Some browsers (Chrome, for example) provide settings that allow users to continue browsing sessions after closing and re-opening the browser. In some cases, this can interfere with the **SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE** setting and prevent sessions from expiring on browser close. Please be aware of this while testing Django applications which have the **SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE** setting enabled.

Comment: @NKSM how can i fix this?